# splitting values and compare with tables using SQL Server Join

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, split

I have two tables called `Components` and `PDF_MSDS`. The `Component` table contains columns `f_chem_name`, `f_component_id` and `f_chem_name` and it contains below sample data.

**Components** table

```
SELECT F_Cas_Number, F_Component_Id, F_Chem_Name 
FROM Components  
WHERE F_Chem_Name = 'CHMNM_17816'
```

OUTPUT

```
F_Cas_Number    F_Component_Id  F_Chem_Name
-------------------------------------------        
CAS_5861         PRD1000826      CHMNM_17816
```

Sample data of `PDF_MSDS` table

```
F_PRODUCT    F_CAS_NUMBERS                         F_COMPONENT_IDS
----------------------------------------------------------------------
360          CAS_5779¿CAS_5861¿CAS_2614¿           3E000685¿3E002268¿3E004960¿3E005217¿PRD1000826¿
```

Now I want display the `f_product` value from the `PDF_MSDS` table by comparing  `F_Cas_Number` and `F_Component_Id` in `Components` table with `F_CAS_NUMBERS` and `F_COMPONENT_IDS` in the `PDF_MSDS` table for the given `f_chem_name` in `Components` table.

But I am not able compare directly using join with `F_Cas_Number` in `Components` table with `F_CAS_NUMBERS` in `PDF_MSDS` table and also `F_Component_Id` in `Components` table with `F_COMPONENT_IDS` in `PDF_MSDS` because multiple `cas_numbers` and `component_ids` are stored in `F_CAS_NUMBERS` and `F_COMPONENT_IDS` columns in `PDF_MSDS` table.

How can I search and compare cas_numbers and component_ids and select particular record.Please help.F_Chem_Name is input parameter for Procedure.

Comment: That's **exactly** the main reason why you should ***never ever*** store multiple values into a single column! That's just a horribly bad design, and it also violates the **first normal form** of database design. Stop doing that **right now** .....

Comment: If you are stuck with this database design and can't change it (or even if you want to change the design), you need to first process the data out into a temp table that you can work with. Search for SQL split string, and use it to create a temporary table with the split out data values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LIKE in your JOIN conditions.

```
JOIN TableB
  ON TableA.Column LIKE '%'+TableB.Column+'%'
```